# How to import a custom module in a MapReduce job?

Tags: python, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have a MapReduce job defined in **`main.py`**, which imports the `lib` module from **`lib.py`**. I use Hadoop Streaming to submit this job to the Hadoop cluster as follows:

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -files lib.py,main.py 
    -mapper "./main.py map" -reducer "./main.py reduce" 
    -input input -output output
```

In my understanding, this should put both `main.py` and `lib.py` into the **distributed cache folder** on each computing machine and thus make module `lib` available to `main`.  But it doesn't happen: from the log I see that files **are really copied** to the same directory, but `main` can't import `lib`, throwing **`ImportError`**.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

**UPD.** Adding the current directory to the path didn't work:

```
import sys    
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(__file__))
import lib
# ImportError
```

though, loading the module manually did the trick:

```
import imp
lib = imp.load_source('lib', 'lib.py')
```

But that's not what I want.  So why does the Python interpreter see other `.py` files in the same directory, but can't import them?  Note that I have already tried adding an empty `__init__.py` file to the same directory without effect.

Comment: Have you checked `sys.path` in `main.py` to make sure the working directory is included ?

Comment: @lmjohns3: yes, working directory is on the classpath. BTW, isn't it automatically included for running script? (just curious)

Comment: I believe that's true for Python scripts that are started on the command-line, but Hadoop streaming might be starting a Python interpreter in another way (not really sure). Either way, I still think this sounds like a path issue. See http://www.litfuel.net/plush/?postid=195 for one possibility to distribute your modules in a different way. Alternatively, try writing your commands into a shell script and passing that for the `-mapper` and `-reducer` command-line arguments.

Comment: @lmjohns3: yeah, I have seen the trick with module, but it puts some restrictions on `main`, while I'm trying to keep importing as simple as possible. The point is to create distributable library that you can just `import`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I posted the question to Hadoop user list and finally found the answer. It turns out that Hadoop doesn't really copy files to the location where the command runs, but instead creates **symlinks** for them. Python, in its turn, can't work with symlinks and thus doesn't recognize `lib.py` as Python module.

Simple **workaround** here is to put both `main.py` and `lib.py` into the same directory, so that **symlink to the directory** is placed into MR job working directory, while both files are physically in the same directory. So I did the following:

1. Put `main.py` and `lib.py` into `app` directory.
2. In `main.py` I used `lib.py` directly, that is, import string is just

   import lib
3. Uploaded `app` directory with `-files` option.

So, final command looks like this:

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -files app 
       -mapper "app/main.py map" -reducer "app/main.py reduce" 
       -input input -output output
```

Comment: Using -files option to upload dozens of files did not work in my hadoop environment.

Answer (score 5):

When Hadoop-Streaming starts the python scripts, your python script's path is where the script file really is. However, hadoop starts them at './', and your lib.py(it's a symlink) is at './', too. So, try to add 'sys.path.append("./")' before you import lib.py like this:

`import sys
sys.path.append('./')
import lib`

Comment: I'm using yarn, which seems to not support -files like the selected answer uses. This worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `-files` and `-archive` switches are just shortcuts to Hadoop's [distributed cache](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) (DC), a more general mechanism that also allows to upload and automatically unpack archives in the zip, tar and tgz/tar.gz formats.  If rather than by a single module your library is implemented by a structured Python package, the latter feature is what you want.

We are directly supporting this in [Pydoop](http://crs4.github.io/pydoop/index.html) since release 1.0.0-rc1, where you can simply build a `mypkg.tgz` archive and run your program as:

```
pydoop submit --upload-archive-to-cache mypkg.tgz [...]
```

The relevant docs are at http://crs4.github.io/pydoop/self_contained.html and here is a full working example (requires [wheel](https://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)): https://github.com/crs4/pydoop/tree/master/examples/self_contained.